# Tkinter Text Widget to be inside Notebook as resizable/streched/font changable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

1. Why I cannot stretch Text widget inside Notebook widget(Tab) with **sticky**?
2. How to get fixed Text widget size while changing font, while **grid_propagate** doesn't give results.
3. How that same window can again be resizable **(weight)** altogether?

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, font


class TextInsideNotebook:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        self.fontSizePx = -20

        # Font
        self.fontspecs = font.Font(family="consolas", size=self.fontSizePx)

        # Notebook
        self.tab = ttk.Notebook(main, width=800, height=600)
        self.tab.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Tab
        self.tab_frame = Frame(self.tab)
        self.tab.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.tab.add(self.tab_frame, text='  NEW FILE ')

        # Text Area
        self.textarea = tk.Text(self.tab_frame, font=self.fontspecs)

        self.textarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.tab_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        # weights
        main.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Bind
        self.main.bind('<Control-MouseWheel>', self.new_font_size)

    def new_font_size(self, event):
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.fontSizePx = self.fontSizePx - 2
        else:
            self.fontSizePx = self.fontSizePx + 2

        self.fontspecs.config(size=self.fontSizePx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = tk.Tk()
    agc = TextInsideNotebook(main)
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I cannot stretch Text widget inside Notebook widget(Tab) with sticky?

The text *does* stick to the edges of the area you've allocated to it. However, you haven't given any rows or columns inside `self.tab_frame` a weight so that row and column is only as wide and tall as the text widget.

If you're only putting the text widget in the frame, it's much easier to use `pack` than grid since it takes only one line of code rather than three:

```
self.textarea.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you wish to stick to using `grid` for some reason, you must give the row and column that contains the text widget a non-zero weight

```
self.tab_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.tab_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.textarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

As a rule of thumb you should always give at least one row and one column a positive non-zero weight in any widget that has children managed by `grid`.

> How to get fixed Text widget size while changing font

What I recommend is to give the widget a small size, such as 1x1, and then let the geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, or `grid`) stretch it to fit the space allocated to it.

```
self.textarea = tk.Text(..., width=1, height=1)
```

> How that same window can again be resizable (weight) altogether?

I don't understand that question. It's never *not* resizable.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, exactly self.tab_frame.grid_row/columnconfigure connects all three answers that I wanted. I was sure that doing that with main frame and to get same result, but not. On each Frame you must repeat doing .grid_row/columnconfigure